# Lowest 'Order' of Radiation

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, gravitational-waves

I've noticed an interesting phenomenon (admittedly from only two data points). In electromagnetism, $A^\mu$ obeys Maxwell's equations: 
$$ \square A^{\mu} = j^\mu . $$
where I've chosen $\mu_0 = \epsilon_0 = 1$ for convenience (Lorentz-Heaviside). Assuming $j^\mu$ varies in time, when you take the multipole expansion of the retarded potential in the far-field approximation, the term corresponding to the change in monopole moment of the charge density (simply the total charge) vanishes (due to the conservation of charge), leaving the dipole term as the leading contribution to electromagnetic radiation. A similar phenomenon occurs in gravitation: here, the dynamical variable is the (trace-reversed) metric perturbation, which, under an appropriate gauge choice satisfies a similar wave equation:
$$ \square h^{\mu\nu} = 16\pi T^{\mu\nu} $$
In this case, we observe that the lowest order for which $h^{\mu\nu}$ is nonvanishing is the quadrupole moment of $T^{00}$, the mass density. I've seen the quadrupole nature of gravity explained under entirely different physical considerations: The dipole moment is shown to vanish by invoking the equivalence principle (ensuring that gravity couples to mass) and the conservation of momentum (ensuring that the center of mass' second derivative vanishes).

Now, I noticed something rather interesting. In a theory where the dynamical variable is a vector, the lowest-order term in the multipole expansion for a time-varying field is a dipole moment. In a theory where the variable is a rank-2 tensor, the lowest order term is a quadrupole moment. Now, if we have a hypothetical tensor $H_{\mu \nu \sigma}$ as the dynamical variable in a theory, would we observe 'octupole radiation'? Does this generalize?

Comment: First, it's either $\nabla^2$ or $\square$ and not $\square^2$. And yes, spin-$s$ massless boson field is radiated by changing multipole moment $l$ only if $l\ge s$.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof of this? I can't exactly see why it's obvious (hence, I asked the question).

Comment: @knzhou, could you post what you currently have figured out? I'd still be interested to see.

Answer (score 1):

I think this follows from the fact that the wave equation for massless spin-$s$ particles (in flat space) can be expanded in [spin-$s$ weighted spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics). Spin-weighted spherical harmonics have the property that they vanish for $\ell < s$. Hence spin $s$ wave have no $\ell < s$ multipoles.

Comment: Can you add more detail? What does it mean that an equation "can be expanded in" these functions? What are the physical meanings of $\ell$ and $s$ in the spin-weighted spherical harmonics -- are they just orbital and spin angular momentum? If so, I don't find it physically clear at all why $\ell < s$, naive addition of angular momentum suggests otherwise.