# Multipole radiation of a wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, radiation

I read that a sound wave (a *scalar wave*) produces monopole radiation, an eletromagnetic wave (a *vector wave*) produces dipole radiation, and a gravitational wave (a *second order tensor wave*) produces quadrupole radiation. How do I make sense of multipole radiation physically? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation) on multipole radiation is informative on the mathematics, but I can't seem to get a physical picture.

Note: my question is different from this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388646/lowest-order-of-radiation), which asks about the pattern of lowest order multipole radiation produced.